# Zero-copy reference a slice of bytes by a step

Tags: rust, reference, slice, vec

I have a large `Vec<u8>` representing the raw pixel values of a gray image. Since the pixel format is actually 16-bit width, two `u8` makes one pixel.

Now I'd like to use the image *as if* it was 8-bit width, so I only take the higher 8-bit part of a pixel.

As an instance, given a raw vec `v = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5]`, how can I view it by a step `2` to a reference `view : &[u8]` (without the need to copy them into a new Vec, for performance), such that `view` can be used equivalent to `&[0,2,4]`. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact thing you're asking for is impossible, because slices are, by definition, continuous chunks of memory. To have an `&[0u8, 2, 4]`, you need to have something equivalent to `[0u8, 2, 4]`, i.e. these exact three bytes positioned directly next to each other.

The thing you're *conceptually* asking for looks like a *stride*, that is, something which yields a sequence of elements while skipping some of them. This can be relatively easily done with iterators, for example, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8d6043405885940212b372bee18cf8a):

```
fn only_first_byte_from_pair<'a>(data: &'a [u8]) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a {
    return data.chunks(2).map(|chunk| chunk[0])
}
```

Alternatively, you can have a look on [`ndarray`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.15.6/ndarray/index.html), which has the relevant functionality out of the box, but could be a bit too complex for the actual task.

Comment: If you need more functionality than a simple iterator (for example, indexing) but without the full power of `ndarray`, you can create a slice-like wrapper struct.